# Firebase Test Lab videos frame rate is too low for instrumentation tests

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

In Firebase Test Lab I can view videos of my tests. However, these videos have too low frame rate, so it's something like screen shots viewed together. 
I want to know if I can make these videos smoother (Increase the frame rate).
I saw that videos generated for `Robo Tests` is much more smoother and has a very satisfactory frame rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no configuration setting that you can simply change.  What you see is what you get.

You are always free to [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features) if you need something more than what's provided.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I found no way to do so, but I wanted to make sure that I didn't miss something.

Answer (score 0):

As Doug already mentioned in his answer there's no setting. What you are observing can have the following reasons:

- For instrumentation tests UI animations are (usually) disabled while for Robo they aren't. So, it only looks choppy, but the video frame rate is the same.
- Frame rate can depend on the device model, or virtual vs physical devices. Video recorded on virtual devices usually has lower quality than video from physical devices, because physical devices provide actual hardware-support for video encoding.

If you feel there's something else wrong contact the Test Lab team via the [Firebase Community](https://firebase.community/) Slack channel #test-lab.

Comment: Thanks maik for your response. I got your point, but I don't think that the first point is the real reason. For example, in the test when I write text into an "EditText", the instrumentation test video shows just two states while for the Ropo test, the dynamic behavior of the writing is shown.

Comment: Are you running on the exact same device type in both cases? From your comments, I would guess that you're running the instrumentation test on a virtual device and the robo test on a physical device?